# What happens to captured heroes when the fight text to gain them is nullified?

Tags: legendary-marvel

Some villain cards like Dracula (from Underworld) and Skrull Queen Veranke and Skrull Shapeshifters (from Skrulls) will capture a hero card beneath them upon entering the city. The fight text says, "Fight: Gain that hero."

If someone attacks that villain after playing Mr. Fantastic's Ultimate Nullifier card, and uses its ability to cancel the fight text, what happens to the abandoned hero? This seems like a legitimate use of that nullifying ability to me, if you want the villain's victory points without adding that hero to your deck.

I've searched online errata and not found anything. Is there any right answer to this? Thanks!